# "Attempt to read property \"view\" on null" After I stop returning MailMessage from VerifyEmail

Tags: php, laravel, sendgrid, laravel-authentication, laravel-mail

I already have the function where I am customizing Laravel default's verify email with my own blade template.

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class VerifyEmail extends \Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\VerifyEmail
{
    use Queueable;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        $actionUrl = $this->verificationUrl($notifiable);
        $explodedLinkSlash = explode('/', $actionUrl);
        $explodedLinkEquals = explode('=', $actionUrl);
        $queryNumber = strtok($explodedLinkSlash[7], '?');
        $expires = strtok($explodedLinkEquals[1], '&');
        $hash = strtok($explodedLinkEquals[2], '&');
        $signature = $explodedLinkEquals[3];
        
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->from('noreply@walor.io', 'Frederik from Walor')
            ->subject('Verify Email Address')
            ->markdown(
                'emails.regular.validation-email',
                [
                    'url' => config('app.frontend_url').'verify-email/'.$queryNumber.'/'.$expires.'/'.$hash.'/'.$signature,
                ]
            );
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

Now that we are switching to SendGrid I want to change to not return a new MailMessage but just call a action that handles Sending a dynamic template with sendgrid

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use App\Actions\SendGridEmailAction;
use App\Helpers\SenGridHelper;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class VerifyEmail extends \Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\VerifyEmail
{
    use Queueable;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        $actionUrl = $this->verificationUrl($notifiable);
        $explodedLinkSlash = explode('/', $actionUrl);
        $explodedLinkEquals = explode('=', $actionUrl);
        $queryNumber = strtok($explodedLinkSlash[7], '?');
        $expires = strtok($explodedLinkEquals[1], '&');
        $hash = strtok($explodedLinkEquals[2], '&');
        $signature = $explodedLinkEquals[3];

        (new SendGridEmailAction())->execute(
            SenGridHelper::MAILS['email_verification']['id'],
            'nikulasoskarsson@gmail.com',
            ['weblink' => config('app.frontend_url').'verify-email/'.$queryNumber.'/'.$expires.'/'.$hash.'/'.$signature],
        );
    }
}
```

However now I keep getting the error

```
"Attempt to read property \"view\" on null"
```

You can see my action here

```
<?php

namespace App\Actions;

use SendGrid;
use SendGrid\Mail\Mail;
use SendGrid\Mail\TypeException;

class SendGridEmailAction
{
    private SendGrid $client;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->client = new SendGrid(config('services.sendgrid.api_key'));
    }

    /**
     * @throws TypeException
     */
    public function execute(
        string $templateId,
        string $to,
        array $data = [],
    ): void
    {
        $email = new Mail();

        $email->setTemplateId($templateId);
        $email->addTo($to);
        $email->setFrom('noreply@walor.io', 'Walor - No reply');
        $email->addDynamicTemplateDatas($data);

        $this->client->send($email);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `toMail` function currently doesn't return anything. Try to add `return null;` at the end of the function to resolve this.